# How call jQuery function in AngularJS controller?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<iframe name='iframe1' id="iframe1" src='http://micro.shoretel.com" frameborder='0' width='660' height='450'></iframe>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("element-selector").css("border-color", "blue");
```

I want to do:

```
app.controller("myCntrl", function ($scope, angularService, $modal) {

        $scope.deletePrepared = function (itm) {
            var getData = angularService.DeletePrepared(itm.ProductId);
            getData.then(function (msg) {
                GetAllPrepared();
            }, function () {
$("iframe").contents().find("element-selector").css("border-color", "blue");});}});
```

What is the mistake can be?

Comment: Well, you are doing the jQuery stuff in the error callback of the promise. Is this the desired behavior - to update the border color to blue on error? Blue is not a color that users normally associate with errors.

Comment: My Goal is call to JS function from Angular contrroller, it is no matter what is I do change the color or another css propertie, I want to see from others who did it, what the right way to call the JS function from Angular Controller.

Comment: What does the element you're trying to select look like?

Comment: @itamar, I am beginning to suspect that his question is more about if that is the _correct_ approach. If that's the case, DOM manipulations don't usually belong in controllers.

Comment: To use jQuery, simply ensure it is loaded before the angular.js file. You can also use the ngJq directive to specify that jqlite should be used over jQuery, or to use a specific version of jQuery if multiple versions exist on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Docs:

> To use `jQuery`, simply ensure it is loaded before the `angular.js` file. You can also use the [`ngJq`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngJq) directive to specify that `jqlite` should be used over `jQuery`, or to use a specific version of jQuery if multiple versions exist on the page.
>
> [—AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("Profile",[])
app.controller("ProfileCtrl", function($scope){
  window.call_from_scope = function(){
        alert('CALLED FROM SCOPE')
      }
  $scope.get_name = function(){
        window.call_from_scope()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Profile" ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
    <button ng-click="get_name()">Click Here</button>
</body>
```

Comment: if you Want you can keep the window function outside the controller or Some other js file also

Comment: So I can replace the    window.call_from_scope() with $("iframe").contents().find("element-selector").css("border-color", "blue");

Comment: Is somebody Knows the simple example with calling JS from controller? the most simple one.

Comment: you donot to replace .you just put inside window.call_from_scope function to your  code it will work.if is not working means cross orgin issue other than that no possible to get Error... can you share what kind of error your getting?

Comment: the problem I have no this operand to click on - .get_name I just want something will change in upload the page, like change the color of text or background.

Comment: this  Code working in my place  try this (if u are loading dynamically ur iframe you have find when the load completed then u have call this function):


window.call_from_scope = function(){
                                alert('CALLED FROM SCOPE')
                                var d = $("iframe").contents().find("a")
                                d.each(function(){
                                        if(this)        
                                                $(this).css('background','red')
                                })
                        }

Comment: Thank You but nothing happened. It is not working. I should try something more simple.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//THIS IS BOTH WAY COMMUNICATION U CAN CALL FROM JS TO CONTROLLER AND CONTROLLER TO JS
window.call_from_scope = function(){
        alert('CALLED FROM SCOPE')
      var myscope= angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app="Profile"]')).scope()
      myscope.return()
  }
var app = angular.module("Profile",[])
app.controller("ProfileCtrl", function($scope){
 
  $scope.get_name = function(){
        window.call_from_scope()
  }
   $scope.return = function(){
    alert('Called from window')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Profile" ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
    <button ng-click="get_name()">Click Here</button>
</body>
```

Comment: THIS IS BOTH WAY COMMUNICATION U CAN CALL FROM JS TO CONTROLLER AND CONTROLLER TO JS

Comment: It is have no errors, just not response any changes, will the problem what I have no .get_name in  $scope.get_name = function(){
        window.call_from_scope()
  }

Comment: Would way You will do if You want just from Angular controller change the prm-search-bar directive background-color for example?

Comment: I have no choice, don;t allow another way run JS code.